# Sort df by date column by month

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sorting, datetime

I have a df that has dates in the following format: yyyy-mm-dd

I imported the data and used parse-dates to read it in as a datetime object:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(file1, encoding="utf-8", sep=',', parse_dates=['Date'])
```

I want to find the max and min temperature and plot them.

I am close.

I am getting the basic plotting (just the max and min lines for now) to work as follows:

```
df1["str_dates"] = df1["Date"].astype({'Date': 'str'})
str_dates_temp = df1.groupby("Date")["str_dates"].unique().to_list()
str_dates = [''.join(x) for x in str_dates_temp]
df1 = df1.sort_values(by="Date", ascending=True)
print(df1.head(), '\n')
print(df1.tail(), '\n')
grouped_max_list = df1.groupby("Date")["Data_Value"].max().to_list()
grouped_min_list = df1.groupby("Date")["Data_Value"].min().to_list()

fig, axe = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 8), facecolor='1.0')
axe.set_facecolor("1.0")
plt.plot(str_dates, grouped_max_list, color='blue')
plt.plot(str_dates, grouped_min_list, color='salmon')
plt.show()
```

The issue is the df is sorted by date.  This means the data is displayed, left to right, by year then month then day.

So I get Jan 2005, Feb 2005, March 2005 ... Dec 2005, Jan 2006, Feb 2006, Mar 2006 ... Dec 2006, and so on.

I want all of the months grouped for plotting purposes.

So I want the df sorted as follows:
Jan 2005, Jan 2006, Jan 2007, ... Jan 2014, Feb 2005, Feb 2006, Feb 2007, ... Feb 2014, and so on.

With my date sorting, my plot looks like this:
[image]

If the data were grouped by month, it would\should look like this:

[image]

I am not sure how to adjust my sort to achieve the desired result.

All I want is assistance with the sorting.  Nothing else.

Comment: You're plotting with `str_dates`. Meaning that matplotlib can only interpret them as words and is trying to order them lexicographically. You should pass them in datetime format

Comment: @Henry Ecker, I am sorting by the datetime column ("Date").  I want to adjust the sort, using that column, to get grouping\sorting by month. My sort needs' enhancement'.

Comment: Yes I understand. I'm just clarifying matplotlib does its own sorting to orient its axes. Regardless of the order of data you have in the DataFrame the axes will ultimately be what your graphing library decides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')).max()
df["Month"] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%b', errors='coerce').dt.month
df = df.sort_values(by="Month").drop(['Month'], axis=1)
```

**Example of the code result:**

- start df:

[image]

- result df:

[image]

Comment: The dates in my df are now sorted by month but not by year.

Comment: I added  a 'Year' column following your recipe and sorted by "Month" and "Year" and it works.